# Get value pairs from dictionaries

Tags: python

Re-edited to make more clear and simple

For below data

```
[
{
    "name": "name1",
    "a_id": "12345",
    "b_id": "0d687c94c5f4"
},
{
    "name": "name2",
    "a_id": "67890",
    "b_id": "0d687c94c5f4"
},
{
    "name": "name3",
    "a_id": "23857",
    "b_id": "9ec34be3d535"
},
{
    "name": "name4",
    "a_id": "84596",
    "b_id": "9ec34be3d535"
},
{
    "name": "name5",
    "a_id": "d82ebe9815cc",
    "b_id": null
}
]
```

How to get

based on "b_id" "0d687c94c5f4":

```
id1 = 12345
id2 = 67890
```

based on "b_id" "9ec34be3d535":

```
id3 = 23857
id4 = 84596
```

Comment: post the final expected result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, I need values for all "a_id"s 12345, 67890, 23857, 84596 but based on "b_id"s . Challenge I am facing is the "b_id"s are same for  some "a_id"s

Answer (score 2):

```
result = collections.defaultdict(list)

for res in response:
    result[res['b_id']].append(res['a_id'])
```

> result:
>
> ```
> defaultdict(list,
>             {'0d687c94c5f4': ['12345', '67890'],
>              '9ec34be3d535': ['23857', '84596'],
>              None: ['d82ebe9815cc']})
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = {
    item['b_id']: [
        subitem['a_id']
        for subitem in response
        if subitem['b_id'] == item['b_id']
    ]
    for item in response
}

print(result)

>>> {'9ec34be3d535': ['23857', '84596'], '0d687c94c5f4': ['12345', '67890'], None: ['d82ebe9815cc']}
```

Comment: this iterates `len(response)` times over `response`

Answer (score 1):

Your request is not very clear.. but I think you mean you want to regroup the list of json with a different key... you can use itertools for that

try this:

```
import itertools
for key, group in itertools.groupby(r, lambda item: item['b_id']):
       print 'b_id', key, [x['a_id'] for x in group]

b_id 0d687c94c5f4 ['12345', '67890']
b_id 9ec34be3d535 ['23857', '84596']
b_id None ['d82ebe9815cc']
```

or in dictionary form

```
for key, group in itertools.groupby(r, lambda item: item['b_id']):
    print {key: [x['a_id'] for x in group]}

{'0d687c94c5f4': ['12345', '67890']}
{'9ec34be3d535': ['23857', '84596']}
{None: ['d82ebe9815cc']}
```

Comment: this only works if the response is already ordered on `b_id`. If it is, this is indeed an elegant solution

Comment: How can I get the data to a variable. If I tried "data = {key: [x['a_id'] for x in group]}" it stores only last value in loop 
>>data 
>>{None: ['d82ebe9815cc']}

Comment: data = {key: [x['a_id'] for x in group]} overwrites data everytime.. if you want to store a dictionary in the end - use a dictionary comprehension

Comment: @MaartenFabré, it still works even if the response in not ordered as all (like the json in the expamle here..), it reorders the given list of dictionaries (not grouped or in any order..) and regroups it according to the given groupby(r, lambda item: item['b_id']) clause..

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby mentions it makes a new group every time the `key` changes, so this might or might not work, depending on the data